# Jquery ajax GET method with an object parse in JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, stringify

I thank you to say your opinion about this misterious behaviour :

This code work :

JS code :

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: "ajouterEntreeParExcel.ajax.php", // url de la page à charger
        data: {"name":"John","date":"05 & 06 mars"},
        cache: false, // pas de mise en cache
        async: false, 
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(jsonRetour){

        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrows){ // erreur durant la requete

        }
    });
```

And PHP code :

```
        $name = $_GET["nom"];
        $date = $_GET["date"];
```

And this one does not work

```
    var dataAjax = {};
    dataAjax["name"] = "John";
    dataAjax["date"] = "05 & 06 mars";
    var entree = JSON.stringify(dataAjax);

    $.ajax({ 
        url: "ajouterEntreeParExcel.ajax.php", // url de la page à charger
        data: entree,
        cache: false, // pas de mise en cache
        async: false, 
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(jsonRetour){

        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrows){ // erreur durant la requete

        }
    });
```

With the same PHP code.
In Debug with firebug, i check the variable "entree", and it is well formated, but i does not get anything in the PHP side.

nota : i prefer to use GET type and not POST type.

Any idea ?

Comment: Never ever use `async: false` ! It is a terrible practice and is now deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to have a version working with an object and with the responde given, this code work :

```
    var dataAjax = {};
    dataAjax["date"] = obj["Date"];
    dataAjax["comite"] = obj["Comité Int.Rég."];


    $.ajax({ 
        url: "ajouterEntreeParExcel.ajax.php", // url de la page à charger
        data: dataAjax,
        cache: false, // pas de mise en cache
        //async: false, 
        //contentType : "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(jsonRetour){
            printValueTraitee = printValueTraitee + '<span class="green">OK</span>';
        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrows){ // erreur durant la requete
            printValueTraitee = printValueTraitee + '<span class="red">KO</span>';
        }
    });
```

So i do not send my data with the JSON format anymore, but juste like an object without stringify it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in the first request you're sending the data as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is what your PHP code is expecting:

```
name=John&date=05 & 06 mars
```

Whereas in the second one you're sending JSON formatted data in the request, eg:

```
'{"name":"John","date":"05 & 06 mars"}'
```

Also note that you should remove `async: false` as it is considered horrendous practice to use it. If you check your console you will see a browser warning about its use.

Comment: but where {"name":"John","date":"05 & 06 mars"} from the first proposition is translate in name=John&date=05 & 06 mars ? Is there a possibility to do the same translation for the "dynamic" version, where i want to send an object as string ?

Comment: It's translated by jQuery internally. You can send the string as JSON if you want, but you need to amend your PHP code to read it properly. Personally I wouldn't bother as PHP is setup by default to work as you already are. There's nothing at all wrong with the code you're using in your first example.